# Unable to start a local dask client outside of interactive IPython

Tags: python, dask

If I'm trying to run:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

from an IPython I get a pop up of my macOS:

[image]

Afterwards, everything works as expected. However, if I put the two lines alone inside a script `foo.py` and I run `python foo.py` it get zillions of errors warnings and I think it fails. Any idea?

Comment: I dont work with macOS but it might be that you need to set the required permissions first - at least thats always an issue when running python scripts on linux.
These steps helped me for linux as well even though they were written for mac so it might fix your problem as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but it seems more related to: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3877#issuecomment-482615113
I'm not sure yet